# C# Ajax URL returning value, but function not hitting success

Tags: c#, json, ajax

The following AJAX code:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{ 'userId' : '" + $('#userId').val() + "' }",
            url: "/User/UserURL",
            success: function (data) {                    
               Do something with data*
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

Is hitting the /User/UserURL function correctly, which is:

```
 public JsonResult UserURL(int userId)
    {
        List<USER> u = (*Get from database using LINQ*).ToList();
        return Json(u, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When I put a debug point and check, the `List<USER> u` has the required value at the end while returning from the `UserURL`. However, at coming back to the page from where AJAX is being called, I get the 'error' alert. Why is it not hitting the success?

**Edit:** If it makes any difference, this is what's going on inside my success:

```
 for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $('input[name="checkbox"]').each(function () {
          if (this.value == data[i].USER_ID) {
             (this).checked = true;
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Put an alert statement inside the success function and see if the alert is displayed. This way we can narrow down the issue.

Comment: why don't you add the [`jqXHR`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) parameter in the error function and then alert `jqxhr.responseText`? or append it to a `div` so that you can see the reason why it is going to the error function.

Comment: Try to change the parameter to int.  `data: { userId: parseInt($('#userId').val()) }, ...`

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran I put an alert in success with `data.length` but it says 0. Checking with the breakpoint, The count is definitely more than 0 I have confirmed that.

Comment: cool. so it is getting into the success function. Try setting the async attribute to true.

Comment: @Eric has it right, but not only because of the int. Rather, he's changed it to passing an object, rather than a string. That will call `JSON.stringify()` on the object, which will produce the correct JSON, which uses double - not single - quotes.

Comment: @Bivo, You may want to use `console.log(arguments)` in your error callback so that you can get an idea of what error is coming back.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I used the jqxhr thing and got what the error was. Fixed it. It had nothing to do with AJAX or C# or anything! There was an error in my code logic (returning circular reference). Case closed guys thanks for your help.

Comment: @BivoKasaju should i post that as an answer then, or do you want post your solution? Either way this question needs to be marked as answered.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid My solution has nothing to do with C#, JSON, AJAX or anything! So I'm not sure what to mark as an answer. Sure, you can post your suggestion as answer, I'll mark that.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to help you find a solution to your problem, since the question didn't describe any specific type of error message.

So with what I am about to show you, you might not need any of our help to diagnose the issue.

Since you say *at coming back to the page from where AJAX is being called, I get the 'error' alert*, you need to do some more digging into why it is doing that, so this should help.

```
error: function (jqhxr) {
            alert(jqhxr);
        }
```

> error
>   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
>
> The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object.

Once that is alerted it will help you diagnose what the real problem is.

Hope this helps!